# Get YouTube URL by field name - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

I have an array in the js file that looks like this:

```
var example = [
 {
 id:'1',
 name: 'name',
 video_url: '???video_url???'
 },
]
```

I want to use an iframe to show the video and this is the example I have with a random video:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pXYWDtXbBB0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I expect to use this page layout for a lot of pages and I wanted to change the URL in the array using JS instead of changing it on the iframe.
Any suggestions?

Comment: So you read the object in the array and set the iframe's src....

Comment: @epascarello Yes, but how does one write that piece of code?

Comment: Do you know how to reference an array? Do you know how to reference a property in an object? Do you know how to reference an element on the page? Do you know how to set an attribute?

Comment: @epascarello I din't, but I searched about all of that and I think I got it now. Had no idea how to proceed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is either create your iFrame, and then using Jay.pepper answer to attr the Youtube video in.

```
var example = [
 {
 id:'1',
 name: 'name',
 video_url: 'pXYWDtXbBB0'
 },
]

var embed_link = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/";
$.each(example, function (name, value) {
      var link = value.video_url;
      console.log(link);
      $('#myyoutube').attr('src',embed_link+link);
     });
```

jsfiddle answer https://jsfiddle.net/55zh66an/

Answer (score 0):

you could try using this

```
 $('.iframe-class').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/pXYWDtXbBB0')
```